# VS Code - Selection to multi cursor

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Does anyone know how to turn an vscode editor selection range into a multi cursor selection?

for instance on this line:
"out of this line I'd like to **select this**|"
[image: selection range]

1. run the key bind
   selection would turn into multi cursor like so
   "out of this line I'd like to **|** select this **|**"

[image: multi cursor selection]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are working with only a single selection:

```js
const selection = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selections[0];

const newSelection1 = new vscode.Selection(selection.start, selection.start);
const newSelection2 = new vscode.Selection(selection.end, selection.end);

vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selections = [newSelection1, newSelection2];
```

You will get the same result selecting left-to-right as right-to-left.

I made this into an extension: [Convert Selection](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.convert-selection) - it works on multiple selections.

[image: convert selection demo]

Here is the entire code of the extension:

```js
const vscode = require('vscode');


/**
 * @param {vscode.ExtensionContext} context
 */
function activate(context) {

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('convert-selection.surround', function () {

      const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
      const selections = editor.selections;
      const newSelections = [];
    
      for (const selection of selections) {
        const newSelection1 = new vscode.Selection(selection.start, selection.start);
        const newSelection2 = new vscode.Selection(selection.end, selection.end);
        newSelections.push(newSelection1, newSelection2);
      }

      editor.selections = newSelections;
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

exports.activate = activate;
```

Comment: Is there a vanilla (without extensions) way of running this on a key bind ? if not, do you have one you'd recommend?

Comment: Since you tagged vscode-extensions I thought you were building one.  It is very easy to do so.  I could package this into an extension if you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I don't think that will be necessary. It seems rioV8s extension suggestion has exactly what I need.

Comment: Well, I have already published the extension `Convert Selection`.  Haven't written the readme yet.  Default keybinding is `Alt+s`, command is `convert-selection.surround`: `Surround selection(s) with multi-cursors`.

Comment: Nice, I downloaded it. What's also nice is it always makes the first multi cursor the active one, so when you click escape it always uses the first one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) v1.10

Execute the command: **SelectBy: Create separate cursors for anchor and active position of the selection(s)** , `selectby.anchorAndActiveSeparate`

It will create new cursors for every anchor and active position of all the current selections. Overlapping cursors are eliminated.

Comment: is there any way to force active be the first of the two regardless of which way you drag?

Comment: @PhilipAarseth I have updated the extension to sort the new selections, so if you first select at the bottom after Esc you are left with the first cursor (lowest line and char)